# Magento fedex error:Commodity country of manufacture is required

Tags: php, magento, fedex

i get below error while generating package for order

```
"Magento fedex error:Commodity country of manufacture is required"
```

while i have added country in **General>Default Country**

how to resolve that error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magento product description add country of manufacture for each product

Comment: any way to set country of manufacture for all product by single setting

Answer (score 2):

solved myself,in magento product description add country of manufacture for each product